# Cannot set python 3.7 as webapp runtime stack in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a webapp with runtime stack python 3.7. I can choose the wanted stack when creating it manually in azure portal, but when I try to do the same thing in my pipeline or cloud shell I get the error messages:

```
jaana@Azure:~$ az webapp create --resource-group my-rg --name test37 --runtime "python|3.7" --plan my-plan
Windows runtime 'python|3.7' is not supported. Please invoke 'az webapp list-runtimes' to cross check
jaana@Azure:~$ az webapp list-runtimes
[
  "aspnet|V4.8",
  "aspnet|V3.5",
  "DOTNETCORE|2.1",
  "DOTNETCORE|3.1",
  "DOTNET|5.0",
  "DOTNET|6.0",
  "node|10.6",
  "node|10.10",
  "node|10.14",
  "node|12-lts",
  "node|14-lts",
  "php|7.3",
  "php|7.4",
  "python|3.6",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|7.0",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|8.5",
  "java|1.8|Tomcat|9.0",
  "java|1.8|Java SE|8",
  "java|7|Tomcat|7.0",
  "java|7|Tomcat|8.5",
  "java|7|Tomcat|9.0",
  "java|7|Java SE|8",
  "java|11|Tomcat|7.0",
  "java|11|Tomcat|8.5",
  "java|11|Tomcat|9.0",
  "java|11|Java SE|8"
]
```

How can I get python 3.7 into my runtimes list ?

Comment: first just update the PHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your App Service Plan is probably Windows, and Windows Plans do not support "PYTHON|3.7". Try switching to Linux App Service Plan and create the webapp under that.

You can check the supported runtimes with *az webapp list-runtimes* and *az webapp list-runtimes --linux* respectively.

Comment: Also, as this is not an Azure DevOps -related question, please change the tags to azure-cli.

Answer (score 0):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, I suppose you are using a `Windows` service plan, which is not supported `python|3.7`, if you use a `Linux` service plan, it will work fine.

[image]